# left a message on my phone

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> Jake left a message on my phone, but I've been busy at work, so I have
> only just seen it.

Would 'left a message on my phone' always be taken to mean a voicemail?

Comment: Surely it might also be a text message?

Comment: If it was a text message wouldn't you say 'texted me' or 'sent me a message' instead? Thanks.

Comment: I would personally assume voicemail. And if the difference were important, I would ask for clarity. I'm an American. The question I would ask would probably be this: "You mean like a voicemail?"

Comment: The phrasing "on my phone" sounds weird to me.  I wonder if it's a non-US English phrasing.  We would usually just say "left a message for me" or "left voicemail", or just "left a message" with the understanding that that means voicemail.

Comment: _On my phone_ is perfectly normal in British English. To a dinosaur like me _left a message_ could be a verbal or written message left with a person!